# how do I fix hinges to sandstone (that is quite soft)

Tags: walls, construction

I have a sandstone wall that I want to fit a gate to.  The sandstone crumbles with little effort. I am concerned any fixings will work loose quickly with any use

Comment: If you can, put a "gate wheel" on the gate to reduce the amount of weight that your hinges carry. (This only works on level ground.)

Answer (score 2):

You could drill out larger holes, then fill with epoxy, then mount the hinges through the epoxy. But that seems like a lot of work.

I'd instead install a post alongside the wall and use the post.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with weak materials, the goal is to spread the load among several attachment points and across a wide area.

You should consider *gate hinges*, preferably those with a long tongue, such as these

[image: gate hinge]

The long section would go on your sandstone surface using the deepest anchors you can use. Consider expansion anchors and bolts rather than screw types.

The larger the hinge on the sandstone side (especially horizontally), and the more attachment points (within reason), the more likely it will survive.

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```